# getDeclaredMethod throws exception

Tags: java, exception, parameters, rpc

I want to write a client server app which communicates via rpc. The code works quite well with functions with no parameters. However, when I try to call a function with a single parameter (more are not supported), it gives me an "NoSuchMethodException".

Here are the important parts:

The Function I want to call:
(rpcserver.CarPark.in)

```java
public boolean in(int num) {
    if(!closed) {
        if (num <= (maxLots - curLots)) {
            curLots += num;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}    

public boolean in() {
    if(!closed) {
        if (curLots < maxLots) {
            curLots += 1;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the code that calls the functions:
(I use procedure[0] for the function name and [1] for the parameter.

```
    if(procedure.length == 1) {
        try {
            Method method = CarPark.class.getDeclaredMethod((String)procedure[0]);
            return method.invoke(park);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Server couldn't find a fitting procedure.");                
        }
    } else {
        // length of 2, more isn't possible
        try {
            System.out.println((String)procedure[0] + ", " +  procedure[1].getClass());
            Method method = CarPark.class.getDeclaredMethod((String)procedure[0], procedure[1].getClass());
            return method.invoke(park,procedure[1]);  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Server couldn't find a fitting procedure." + e);                
        }
    }
```

Strangely, the function returnes this: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: rpcserver.CarPark.in(java.lang.Integer)`
However, the println command gives me this: `in, class java.lang.Integer`

So why can I call procedures with no parameters but have problems with parameters?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what arguments you're passing in, but my initial suspicion is that `procedure[1]` is `Integer` instead of `int.class`. (And you really should encapsulate that array into an object; it's confusing to read, and it'll be you confused in a few months when you come back to it.)

Comment: procedure[1] got set with Integer.parseInt(string); I am quite bad with Java so what's the difference in int.class and Integer?

What do you mean with the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the version of `CarPark.in` you're trying to get takes a primitive integer, and `getDeclaredMethod` is looking for one that takes a `java.lang.Integer`, which is not the same thing. If you pass `int.class` or `Integer.TYPE` to `getDeclaredMethod`, you'll see that it'll be able to find the method correctly.

Without seeing your full code isn't a bit hard to suggest a solution that works for you, but just keep in mind the distinction between primitives types and their boxed equivalents, and be wary of [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: Hi, 

I have to parse an input from the user and then cast the variable if it "looks" like an Integer. I do this with something like this:
`int num = Integer.parseInt((String)procedure[1]);` and if this was possible, I replace the String with int. `procedure[1] = num`.

Comment: @ruhigbrauner You haven't shown what type `procedure` is; I'm assuming it's `Object[]`. In that case, the assignment `procedure[1] = num` will implicitly box `num` to a `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: Yep. How can I cast String to Int with the primitive type? Otherwise I would have to check what type the parameter is and then use the primitive int for `getDeclaredMethod`.

Comment: It workes if I check if `rocedure[1].getClass() == Integer.TYPE` and then use `getDeclaredMethod((String)procedure[0], Integer.TYPE)`. I don't have to tell you, how ugly that looks.

Java is so messed up!

Comment: @ruhigbrauner Java has its downsides, but its reflection system is about as clean as you can get for a strongly-typed language. A lot of the issue is simply that you're doing this all yourself by hand instead of using a library (or perhaps Groovy) to handle it for you.

Comment: I'm a student and I think learning how RPC works with low level programming makes more sense than lerning how to use a libary. But you are right that once you get it, a libary should to the trick (and even much smoother)

Regardings the messed up java: I meant Integer.TYPE, Integer.class etc..